# Problem with updating password on my popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

WhenI try to update passwords on mysql db, I'm using html for my panel with JS and CSS. I made a popup into html using an anchor with CSS, but when I click to update passwords nothing happens.

This is where I have my popup its a panel that the users login whit email and password.

```
section  id="section4" >
    <h2>MIS DATOS</h2>
    
      <p class="intro">Nombre: <?php echo ' '; echo $nombre; echo ' '; echo $apellido ?><br>
      PROVINCIA: <?php echo ' '; echo $prov; ?> <br>
      DIRECCIÓN: <?php echo ' '; echo $dir; ?><br>
      CP: <?php echo ' '; echo $cp; ?><br>
      CUIT: <?php echo ' '; echo $cuit; ?><br>
      TELÉFONO: <?php echo ' '; echo $cel; ?><br>
      E-MAIL: <?php echo ' '; echo $email; ?></p>

   <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  

        <p class="envio">
       <a href="#popup" style="text-decoration:none" color="#FFF" class="button"><font color="white" SIZE="2">Cambiar contraseña</font></a>
          </p>
              <div id="popup" class="overlay">
            <div id="popupBody">
                <h3 align="center">Cambiar contraseña</h3>
                <a id="cerrar" href="#">&times;</a>
             <form action="../password.php" method="post">
              
                    <div class="contenedor-inputs" align="center">
                        <br>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password actual" class="introd" name="pdw_orig" > <br>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password nuevo" class="introd" name="pdw_new1"> <br> 
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password nuevo" class="introd" name="pdw_new2"> <br>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="cambiar" name="pwd" action ="../password.php">
                    </div>
```

the css its ok but i put it too (It's only for the "popup").

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 2.35;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: opacity 700ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
#popupBody{
    width: 15%;
    padding: 0%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #CCC;
    background: #1e3466;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 20% auto;    
}
#cerrar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 10px;
    transition: all 200ms;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
.button {
  width: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #DE680C;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

.introd {
  margin-top:20px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  }

section h3 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #DE680C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-animation: float-in-right 0.45s ease;
  animation: float-in-right 0.45s ease;
}

a.button {
      text-align: center;
     width: 23%;
   
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
     border: 0 none;
}
```

and now where the problem lies (the php code)

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESION['email'])){
    header('location: index.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['pwd']))
{
    include_once("con_db.php");

    $usuario = $_SESSION['email'];

    $pdw_orig = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pwd_orig']);
    $pdw_new1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pwd_new1']);
    $pdw_new2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pwd_new2']);

        $pwd_orig = hash('sha512', $pwd_orig);

        $pwd_new1 = hash('sha512', $pwd_new1);

        $pwd_new2 = hash('sha512', $pwd_new2);

        $sqla = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM datos Where email = $usuario");
        $rowa = $sqla->fetch_array();

        if($rowa['password'] == $pass_orig ){

            if ($pwd_new1 == $pwd_new2){

                $passUpdate = $mysqli->query("UPDATE datos SET password = '$pwd_new1' WHERE email = $usuario");
                    if($update) { echo "<script> alert('Cambio de contraseña correcto! deberá iniciar sesión nuevamente');window.location='panel.php'</script>";
                sleep(15);
                header ('location: ../index.php'); 
            }else {
                echo "<script> alert('Las contraseñas nuevas no coinciden!');window.location='panel.php'</script>";
             }

            }

        }else{"<script> alert('Tu contraseña actual no coincide');window.location='panel.php'</script>";
        } 

 ?>
```

the archive con_db.php its working fine because I'm using it always when I need to do something on my db.

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: and what is the problem? is the new pw not getting saved? do you get an error? do you hit the server at all?

Comment: typo here: `if(isset($_SESION['email'])){ header('location: index.php'); }` must be `if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){ header('location: index.php'); }`... maybe that's already the problem?

Comment: If you add some `echo` or `var_dump` in your code, do you get the wanted value after your `isset['pwd']` ? And you wrote `$_SESION['email']`, it's `$_SESSION` no ?

Comment: i dont receive nothing, the pw not saved and nothing the popup close and nothing happens. @Argee

Comment: @MickaëlLeger yes its $_SESSION['email'] miss click typing here.

Comment: @Argee no its because if users not logged trying to access to this section they will be redirected to login page that its index.php. 
this is Panel.php

Comment: **$_SESION['email']** will cause an error, which probably the reason your process not completed and no data is stored!

Comment: @Moayad.AlMoghrabi its only a miss click here its ok on my code. sry for this .

Comment: I add an echo 

if (isset($_POST['pwd']))
{
 $pass = $_POST['pwd'];
 echo $pass;
} 

and when i click nothing happens too... its very rare...

Comment: try to var_dump $_POST

Comment: @Sfili_81 nothing too... tomorrow i will replace popup for a single html page and i will try, maybe the problem can be stored in how u create the popup

Comment: So it's seem your form does not submitted

Comment: @Sfili_81 
correct, so now my question is if the way to create the popup can make my form not send?

Comment: Check if you have errors in your browser console

Comment: I just did a test from the same form, changing where it executes the action for another file that adds the tracking numbers of the packets to another table in the same database and if it sends it, so even more rare

Comment: @Sfili_81 i check it and nothing only suggest of autocomplete password

Comment: is it necessary to declare `action ="../password.php"` twice? on the form and submit button?

Comment: @jasmine I try not declare it coz i declare it on password.php/only declare in one and nothing too.

Comment: There's no reason not to use `real_escape_string` on `$usuario` as well. Don't trust any data being used in sql. Escape/use prepared statements on anything not hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your `SELECT` query here; `$sqla = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM datos Where email = $usuario");`

You've declared the variable directly inside the string, so it's actually looking for an email that matches the string "$usuario" not what the PHP variable passes. Instead try;

`$sqla = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM datos WHERE email = '" . $usuario . "'");`

edit--- also the WHERE should be in all capitals, and I missed that you need to enclose the variables in single quotes.

Same again for your update query...  `$passUpdate = $mysqli->query("UPDATE datos SET password = '$pwd_new1' WHERE email = $usuario");`

should be this -> `$passUpdate = $mysqli->query("UPDATE datos SET password = '" . $pwd_new1 . "' WHERE email = '" . $usuario . "'");`

Comment: i try a lot of things, i make another html with email, password and new password and nothing happens! 
i can write but not update on my db i don't know what's happening!

Comment: @alejandro yes see my answer for a solution please and give it a try. You've written the database query wrong.

Comment: i try and nothing, but now i change my panel and i will try it again. if it works i will post it. 
Thanks!

Comment: ok I think my answer is wrong, the variables need to be enclosed in single quotes too, will update my answer

Answer (score -1):

Please change your PHP code to the below

I removed some code lines I think they do nothing **ex(window.location='panel.php')**

**Make sure you have declared the variable $update probably or check if isset**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    header('location: index.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['pwd']))
{
    include_once("con_db.php");

    $usuario = $_SESSION['email'];

    $pdw_orig = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pwd_orig']);
    $pdw_new1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pwd_new1']);
    $pdw_new2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pwd_new2']);

    $pwd_orig = hash('sha512', $pwd_orig);
    $pwd_new1 = hash('sha512', $pwd_new1);
    $pwd_new2 = hash('sha512', $pwd_new2);

    $sqla = $mysqli->query("SELECT password FROM datos Where email = $usuario");
    $rowa = $sqla->fetch_array();

    if($rowa['password'] == $pwd_orig ){
        if ($pwd_new1 == $pwd_new2){
            $passUpdate = $mysqli->query("UPDATE datos SET password = '$pwd_new1' WHERE email = $usuario");
            if($update) {
                echo "<script> alert('Cambio de contraseña correcto! deberá iniciar sesión nuevamente');</script>";
                header ('location: ../index.php');
            }else {
                echo "<script> alert('Las contraseñas nuevas no coinciden!');</script>";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "<script> alert('Tu contraseña actual no coincide');</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I will remake the panel.php code and use the form without the popup feature coz nothing is working as a popup :(

Comment: Nothing happen! i don't know what is the problem but i will modify it an try in another page.